# What is meaning of "verlustbehafteteren"?

Tags: meaning

Here is a sentence from book:

> Wenn möglich, bevorzugen wir die direkte Kommunikation und vermeiden die meist deutlich aufwendigeren und verlustbehafteteren indirekten Kommunikationstechniken.

I do understand verlust = loss

Is behafteteren similar to behaftet?

Comment: Wenn an etwas Verlust haftet ist es verlustbehaftet. Die Steigerungsform ist verlustbehafteter. Manche Grafikkompressionsverfahren sind verlustbehafteter als andere.

Comment: It should be noted that this is an example of terrible German word building. Verlust and Anhaften are contradictions and simply don't go together. A painful word and imo only acceptable in the context of data compression.

Comment: For me the word is fully OK. I see not really a contradiction, "behaftet" can refer to different attributes, so it does mean "attributed with loss". "Verlustfrei", the opposite, sounds a little bit better, though. If someone doesn't like the word: Use "nicht verlustfrei" ! The pair "verlustarm/verlustreich" shows why the word "verlustbehaftet" is needed- to sum up the two. And I have no quick idea of a better one. "Verlustreich" comes near, but contains a valuation which is not the main idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

behafteter is the **"comparative"** form of `behaftet`

> behaftet
>   behafteter
>   am behaftetsten

now this comparative form is inflected to match the feminine gender.
you just change the stem to our comparative form and the result is:

> behafteteren

a fitting translation would maybe be:

```
more afflicted
```

in combination with *Verlust* this becomes:

```
afflicted wit losses --> lossy  
more afflicted with losses --> lossier
```

this makes the whole sentence translate to:

```
If possible, we prefer direct communication and avoid the considerably 
lossier and more laborious means of indirect communication
```